# Overwrite Django ImageField to accept absolute URIs as well as files

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

What ImageField does under the hood , is that is stores the image path as string in the db.
I would like to overwrite the field in such a way, that it can accept either a binary image file or absoulte URI path and return the path as string and store it as char in the db.

Which method would have to be overwritten to achieve this operation ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without overriding `ImageField()` you can do those things using one extra `URLField()` like this...

#### models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to ='Products')
    img_abs_url = models.URLField(blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

#### form.py

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = "__all__" 
        exclude = ['img_abs_url']
```

#### views.py

```
def HomeView(request):
  form = ProductForm()
  products = Product.objects.all()
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ProductForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
      product_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
      image = form.cleaned_data['image']
      create_product = Product.objects.create(name=product_name,image=image)
      create_product.img_abs_url = request.build_absolute_uri(create_product.image.url)
      create_product.save()
  context = {'form': form, 'products': products}
  return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

#### Output (admin panel)

[image]

Comment: Your answer refers to Django , not django rest framework. I would rather not imlement additional fields, but have one field. I guess it would require to overwrite methods like get_db_prep_value and to_python.